# Difference between qdel and kill commands

Tags: linux, hpc

Are there any differences between running qdel command or kill-9  to kill a job that is running using several compute nodes on a HPC cluster?

The effect of kill -9 seems to be immediate while qdel takes 5-10 minutes to change the job status from running (R) to canceled (C) before it stops.

Answer (score 3):

`kill -9` is a sledgehammer, machine gun and nuclear bomb all wrapped in one.  Processes killed by `kill -9` get no chance to clean up any resources they may have allocated.  `kill -9` will not directly remove your jobs from the job queue.

Think of `kill -9` as the zombies in World War Z.  Kill at all costs, no matter what.

As I understand it, qdel is a little more friendly in that it does 2 things, not necessarily in the order listed.

- a controlled stop of a job and allows it to clean up
- removes the job from the job queue

You can think of qdel as Dr. Kevorkian...  He's all nice and friendly and wants to help you so he cooperates to a point...  But ultimately, he's there to kill you too.